# Convert integer to string preserving order

Tags: string, code-challenge, integer, conversion

The quest is to convert an integer to a string in such a way that 1. the order is preserved 2. using the least number of characters in the string.

Let's say I have an integer X; the objective is to create a function `f` (and respective inverse, `g`, such that:

#### Conditions

1. `f(X) is a utf-8 string for all integer X`
2. `g(f(X)) = X`
3. Ordering is preserved. That is, if I have another integer Y, X > Y implies f(X) > f(Y)
4. The integer means it **can be** negative
5. Assume integers in `[-2^63, 2^63 - 1]`

#### Winning criterion

1. The answer must fulfill the conditions above
2. Make `f(X)` represent the number in the least number of UTF-8 characters.
3. Of answers complying with 1 and 2, smallest code wins (sum of code of `f` and code of `g`)

#### Example

(Python)

```
def f(x):
    return '%019d' % x  # log10(2^63 - 1) ~ 18.9

def g(x):
    return int(x)
```

Notice that it is not clear that `f` is optimal since it always uses the same number of characters (independent of x).

This is my first challenge here and I'm not sure if this fits this Q&A, but it seemed to me a nice and useful problem. I'm also trying to solve it.

Comment: Comments purged as they were obsolete; please notify me of any lost information.

Comment: So you want to ***represent*** any integer using the smallest chars? Would something like `f=base64encode(X)` , `g=base64tobase10(X)` be acceptable?

Comment: @user80551, can you show that that preserves ordering, (condition 3.)? (I added numbers to the conditions so we can refer to them)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão base 64 is not much different from any other base. Your question is unclear as it mentions `characters` without mentioning the encoding i.e. utf-8/16/whatever. Given an infinite number of unique characters, any integer can be represented using only one of those characters. VTC as unclear.

Comment: @user80551, I'm sorry, I didn't knew so well utf-8; would it make more sense if I ask for the size in memory instead of number of chars? This is the original spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Now this is simply asking to store it as an int (C long?) so there is NOTHING to do. Storing the integers as binary is the only solution now that you ask for storing according to bytes.

Comment: Meh, I have no time for this. I thought was an interesting problem for this website, but it seems I'm not qualified enough to pose it in the correct way. Thanks @user80551 for pointing out the problems. Flagging to close.

Comment: Add an objective tag.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão I have made the question consistently about UTF-8 characters. I agree with user80551's comment on May23 at 8.22 that memory size makes this challenge too trivial. Unfortunately it's not uncommon for new users' questions to get shot down in this way. Writing a good question is difficult I encourage you to look around and answer a few questions, and when you know what we're about, post another one. Also we have these facilities to help question askers: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1596/15599 and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/15599

Comment: @steveverrill, thanks for the input and for the changes. I'm aware of how the things work here, but I didn't expecting to be so difficult to write a question xD

Comment: @J.C.Leitão   @steveverrill    Could you please elaborate what is meant by `Ordering is preserved. That is, if I have another integer Y, X > Y implies f(X) > f(Y)`. The function `f` returns a string so what exactly is meant by `f(X) > f(Y)` ? The question is much better now so I retracted my down-vote.

Comment: @user80551. Not my question, I only took the concept and moulded it slightly into a reasonably non-trivial challenge. My interpretation is this: ASCII strings have a lexical order: `1, 10, 11, 9, 99, A, AARDVARK, ANTELOPE...ZEBRA, a, aardvark, antelope, zebra` (Absence of character *n* in the string counts as below ASCII 0. Note that in case-sensitive ASCII, `Z` comes before `a`, so most dictionaries are case-insensitive. String representations of numbers also suffer from such a simple definition, as can be seen by my examples.)  It's the same for UTF-8 strings, but more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 4 per integer, 115 in code

```
sub f{pack W4,map{$_|1<<($x<0?16:17)}unpack n4,pack"q>",$x=pop}sub g{unpack"q>",pack n4,map{$_&65535}unpack W4,pop}
```

**Caveat:** This only works if Perl has 64-bit integers. This is true if `perl -V:ivsize` gives 8.

If `perl -V:byteorder` says 87654321, I believe that you may golf both `"q>"` into `"q"`, for 113 characters, but I have no 64-bit SPARC to test this.

The strings returned by `f` and passed to `g` are **text strings**, not binary strings. A text string is a sequence of Unicode codepoints. A binary string is a sequence of bytes. The order of the strings preserves the order of the integers when one encodes each text string in UTF-8 and checks the lexical order of the UTF-8 bytes.

### Facts about UTF-8

1. Valid codepoints for UTF-8 are from 0 to 0xd7ff, and from 0xe000 to 0x10ffff. See [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629). This makes 1112064 valid codepoints. Surrogates from 0xd800 to 0xdfff are not valid in UTF-8.
2. Strings have the same lexical order in Unicode codepoints and in UTF-8 bytes. It is enough to put the codepoints in order, then the UTF-8 bytes are also in order.

### Scheme of conversion

Because 1112064<sup>3</sup> < 2<sup>64</sup> < 1112064<sup>4</sup>, there is no scheme that can save every 64-bit integer in 3 or fewer codepoints. Some schemes would use a maximum of 4 codepoints and an average of less than 4. My simple scheme uses 4 codepoints for every integer.

I unpack each 64-bit integer into four unsigned 16-bit integers. To preserve the order of negative integers before positive integers, I put negative integers in plane 1 (Supplementary Multilingual Plane), and non-negative integers in plane 2 (Supplementary Ideographic Plane).

Negative example:

- -9118070288978897167
- 0x81761b61bc5e96f1
- 0x8176 0x1b61 0xbc53 0x96f1
- 0x18176 0x11b61 0x1bc53 0x196f1

Postive example:

- 6359689164524478505
- 0x584227999d61e029
- 0x5842 0x2799 0x9d61 0xe029
- 0x25842 0x22799 0x29d61 0x2e029

### Are 0x1fffe, 0x1ffff, 0x2fffe, 0x2ffff valid in UTF-8?

My scheme uses the Unicode noncharacters 0x1fffe, 0x1ffff, 0x2fffe, 0x2ffff. Perl refuses to encode these in UTF-8.

```
$ perl -MEncode -e 'encode "utf-8", "\x{2fffe}", Encode::FB_CROAK' 
"\x{2fffe}" does not map to utf8 at /usr/libdata/perl5/amd64-openbsd/5.16.3/Encode.pm line 160.
```

[Unicode Corrigendum #9](http://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html) clarifies that Unicode noncharacters like 0x2fffe are valid in Unicode strings. There is no requirement to reject them in UTF-8 as Perl is doing. Python, Ruby and Tcl do not reject noncharacters in UTF-8.

The workaround for Perl is to use 'utf8' and not 'utf-8' to encode strings. The 'utf8' encoder skips the checks in the strict 'utf-8' encoder.

### Ungolfed version

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Convert 64-bit integer to Unicode string.
sub f {
    my $x = shift;

    # Unicode plane = 0x10000 if $x < 0, 0x20000 else
    my $p = 1 << ($x < 0 ? 16 : 17);

    # 1. Pack $x as big-endian signed 64-bit integer "q>".
    # 2. Unpack four big-endian unsigned 16-bit integers "n4".
    # 3. Add Unicode plane.
    # 4. Pack four Unicode characters "W4".
    pack "W4", map({ $_ | $p } unpack("n4", pack("q>", $x)));
}

# Convert Unicode string to 64-bit integer.
sub g {
    # Unpack characters, remove plane, pack and unpack integer.
    unpack "q>", pack("n4", map({ $_ & 65535 } unpack("W4", shift)));
}

# Test program: verify that a lexical sort on UTF-8 octets preserves
# the order of these integers.
use Encode;
my @integers = (-9223372036854775808, -4611686018427387904,
                -9999, -1, 0, 5, 44, 333, 2222, 11111,
                4294967295, 9223372036854775807);
my @strings = map { f $_ } @integers;
@strings = sort { encode('utf8', $a) cmp encode('utf8', $b) } @strings;

my $want = join ',', @integers;
my $have = join ',', map({ g $_ } @strings);
if ($want eq $have) {
    printf "ok\n";
}
else {
    die "not ok: $want ne $have";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 185

```
$s=32767
function f($x){$a='';while($x){$r=$x%$s;$a+=[char]($r+$s)
[long]$x=[bigint]::divide($x,$s)};$a}
function g($x){$a=0;0..($x.length-1)|%{$a+=($x[$_]-$s)*[bigint]::pow($s,$_)};$a}
```

### Ungolfed

```
$shift = 32767

function f($number) {
    $string = ''
    while($number) {
        $remain = $number % $shift
        $string += [char]($remain+$shift)
        [long]$number = [bigint]::divide($number, $shift)
    }
    $string
}

function g($string) {
    [long]$number = 0
    0..($string.length-1)|%{$number += ($string[$_]-$shift)*[bigint]::pow($shift, $_)}
    $number
}
```

At most, the output will be length 5.

```
> f ([long]::MaxValue)
耆耟耯耟耇
> g '耆耟耯耟耇'
9223372036854775807
> f ([long]::MinValue)
翷翟翏翟翷
> g '翷翟翏翟翷'
-9223372036854775808
```

Comment: Oh, so we consider one Unicode character as one character?